# migrate sdf file to sql server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I created code first approach application mvc and it created sdf file db. Now I want to migrate that sdf file to sql server.

When I double click on sdf, It says message like `This is not a valid SQL Server Compact Database file or this file version is not supported by current SQL Server Compact Engine.`

I want to migrate,sync data to sql server of any better approach for future, how can I migrate db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible reason for the error message is that you do not have the correct version of SQL Server Compact installed on your development machine.

The current version is 4.0, but your application might still be using 3.5. Find out which version it is and check the folder *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition* to see if there's a directory with that version name. If there isn't, download and install it ([3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5783), [4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876)).

If you are using SqlCE 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 Pro or higher, you can migrate the sdf's structure and data using [ErikEJ's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej) [SQL Server Compact Toolbox 3.3.0.4](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) which is available through Visual Studio's Extension Manager.

After you have installed the Toolbox, the migration steps are as follows:

1. Using the Toolbox, connect to your sdf file within Visual Studio.
2. From the context menu, choose *Script Database > Script Database Schema and Data* (do not choose *Script Database Schema and Data with BLOBS*). This will save one or more '.sqlce' script files, depending on how large your sdf is.
3. In your SQL Server instance, create an empty target database.
4. Locate the SQLCMD.exe of your Sql Server installation. For SQL Server 2008 it typically is at *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn*. Open a regular cmd.exe with administrator rights and navigate to the directory containing SQLCMD.exe.
5. From there, execute:

> sqlcmd -S [sql server instance name] /d [target database name] -i
>   [full path][filename].sqlce

If you have multiple sqlce files, you can reference them in the same command like this:

> sqlcmd -S [sql server instance name] /d [target database name] -i
>   [full path][filename_0].sqlce -i [full path][filename_1].sqlce -i
>   [full path][filename_2].sqlce

The server option -S needs to be a capital. Good luck.